# Cannot run bash script from crontab when it works from command line bash

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I have a strange problem of being to able to run a bash script from commandline but not from the crontab entry for root. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

```
* * * * 1-5 root /home/xxxxxx/jmeter/VerificationService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jmeter-cron-randomise.sh >> /home/xxxxxxx/jmeter/VerificationService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/cron.log
```

if i run the script from the cmd line using bash it works fine but fails with sh with following error:

```
jmeter-cron-randomise.sh: 7: jmeter-cron-randomise.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "  % 1 "
```

Having googled the problem it seems like stand shell doesn't have the same maths operators like % (modulus) like bash. Not sure why the cron job is failing in the script? i am assumming its because its not using the bash shell? It's definitely being fired by the cron daemon (can see it in /var/log/syslog ). Any help much appreciated.

script causing the problems

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Running the jmeter-cron-randomiser script


script="/home/xxxxxxx/jmeter/VerificationService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jmeter-cron.sh"    

min=$(( 1 * 1 ))
rmin=$(( $RANDOM % $min ))

echo  "min = ${min}";
echo  "rmin = ${rmin}"

at -f "$script" now+${rmin}min
```

Comment: Does your script begin with a shebang, i.e. `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: yes it does #!/bin/bash

Comment: i think the key is the difference between running the sh and the bash script and why there is an arithmetic exception with sh but not with bash from the command line. I think thats where its failing when its fired from cron.

Comment: This script will always be ran with "bash", then, so long as it is present on the system.

Comment: This will probably require more information about your script if you want help troubleshooting its behavior.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo Running the jmeter-cron-randomiser script
 
script="/home/xxxxx/jmeter/VerificationService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jmeter-cron.sh"    
 
min=$(( 1 * 1 ))
rmin=$(( $RANDOM % $min ))

echo  "min = ${min}";
echo  "rmin = ${rmin}"

at -f "$script" now+${rmin}min
'

Comment: Please update your original question and use appropriate formatting for readability.

Comment: i am varying the times for testing purposes but it basically something i picked up from net for randomly firing off another script in the next x mins/hours etc

Comment: Upon further inspection, I think that $RANDOM does not exist in your script because cron launched from a non-bash shell like you said.

Comment: yes thats the crux of the problem. when I run from sh $RANDOM is not resolved but is from bash

Comment: What is the exact name of the `crontab` file? `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: i am running under default root so its crontab but the `/etc/crontab` is the system crontab and does have the entry `SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` ?

Comment: If you're using root's crontab (that is, if you're editing it using `crontab -e` while logged in as root), you shouldn't put the username in the cronjob command. Remove the word `root` before the command. You should only put a username when adding cronjobs in `/etc/crontab`. And there are a lot of troubleshooting steps you can do here mate. Comment out everything on the script and just put some echo lines that append to a file, like `echo $SHELL > /home/xxxxx/tesfile` just to see if it actually works. Then add in your script lines but remove the `$RANDOM` var to see if it works. Troubleshoot.

Answer (score 4):

I note in the [crontab(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html) man page, this:

> The  ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>          run.  The entire command portion  of  the  line  will  be  executed  by
>          **/bin/sh**  or  by  the  shell  specified  in  the  SHELL  variable of the
>          cronfile.

So, you may want to specify bash either with

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

or, as the above affects all cron scripts, this

```
* * * * 1-5 root bash /home/xxxxxx/jmeter/VerificationService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jmeter-cron-randomise.sh >> /home/xxxxxxx/jmeter/VerificationService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/cron.log
# ...............^^^^
```

Comment: already tried the `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the crontab entry and also  and but no luck.

Comment: meant to say that i tried the 
`SHELL=/bin/bash in the crontab entry`
 and also the  
`* * * * 1-5 root bash /home/xxxxxx/jmeter/Verif..`
but no luck

Comment: after debugging a little further the problem is with $RANDOM (see above)

Comment: @kal: you should include the output you get from cron. By reading the question, it seems like the error you are getting is `arithmetic expression: expecting primary`. But by reading your comments, it seems you are getting another error

Comment: FWIW, the crontab manpage doesn't say that the script is executed by `/bin/sh`; it says that the **command** is executed by `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

The crontab **does** run the script with `bash`;

But you're running it recursively with `at`.

And `at` uses `/bin/sh`.

Because of an earlier problem, the time specification for `at` is `now+0min` - so it's running again just at the end.

That run fails, so there is no loop, at least.

The problem leading to the `now+0min` is that `n % 1` is 0, so `$RANDOM % 1` = 0, and `rmin` = 0.

Add a second line

```
set -x
```

to the script for better logging, you'll the last line with the 0 timespec.

Comment: He is running a different script with `at`, `jmeter-cron.sh` vs `jmeter-cron-randomise.sh`

Comment: yes there are 2 scripts involved here. the flow is cron --> `jmeter-cron-randomise.sh` ---> `jmeter-cron.sh`

Comment: @MGodby I see, didn't notice - so he should post that script. By the way, that explains the wrong line number in the error: the `%` is iin line 8, not 7. So I suspect the other script is similar, with an `%` expression in line 7.

Comment: @kal can you confirm the line number? Maybe we do not need the other script actually.

Comment: hurray! the problem is resolved by directly editing the /etc/crontab to use `SHELL=/bin/bash `

Comment: thanks for your time guys but i am not sure why its worked with the system wide crontab file?

Comment: Oh, I thought you had said you tried that already a while ago?! But looking closely at the comments on the other question, you did not confirm with "i tried the SHELL=/bin/bash in the crontab", but "i tried the SHELL=/bin/bash in the crontab entry"... tricky...

Comment: You can not use the user column in a different crontab - only in the system crontab.

Comment: @kal So it was the personal crontab of usere root? But then, it should have failed before even starting your script, when trying ro run the command `root`, right?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel you can have root user in the root user's crontab file (ie. crontab -e once your logged in as root) but the root user also uses the /etc/crontab or thats what i understands from the docs at [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).
For some reason the $RANDOM was not being resolved because the root users crontab entry for bash shell etc. were not being honoured and the /etc/crontab are.